# kafka pod not able to find kafka_connect_run.sh so pod is not able to start

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/opt/kafka/kafka_connect_run.sh": stat /opt/kafka/kafka_connect_run.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

i am getting this in kubectl kafka connector pod which can pull image successfully but not able to start because "unable to start container process: exec: "/opt/kafka/kafka_connect_run.sh": stat /opt/kafka/kafka_connect_run.sh: no such file or directory: unknown" and image name "k3d-registry.localhost:5000/kafka-connect-debezium-postgresql:1.0.0

and I am using strimzi-kafka-operator ver 0.31.1 and kafka connect version 3.2.0

Comment: provide more details about like which image/version you are using? when you are getting the error?

Comment: i am using k3d-registry.localhost:5000/kafka-connect-debezium-postgresql:1.0.0 this image and I am getting error after creating kafka-connect-dev pod which is running local cluster

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't come with `kafka_connect_run.sh` script.

`connect-distributed.sh` is the existing entrypoint for Kafka Connect images from Confluent, for example.

If you want to run Connectors in k8s, then look at using [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io) KafkaConnect resources.

Comment: Actually it is coming inside image which is successfully pulled "k3d-registry.localhost:5000/kafka-connect-debezium-postgresql:1.0.0" but that /opt/kafka/kafka_connect_run.sh not able to find by kubectl kafka pod .I don't it is a root user permission issue or other

Comment: The error says it is trying to `stat` that shell script. The error is not related to finding Kafka brokers. But you'd do that with env-vars. As suggested, however, Strimzi can also deploy and manage Debezium (and Kafka) for you